# Find the records which are not successful

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am a beginner in SQL query. I need to find the Error1 records in the table which has not yet been successful.

My table looks like this:

```
ImportId    LineNumber   Status
---------------------------------
195             6        Success
195             5        Success
195             5        Error1
195             6        Error1
195             7        Error1
195             8        Success
195             9        Error2
```

This query does not return row with importId 195 and linenumber 7

```
select * 
from Table1 
where not exists (select success.ImportID, success.LineNumber 
                  from Table1 success 
                  join 
                      (select ImportID, LineNumber
                       from Table1 
                       where status = 'Error1') overlap on overlap.linenumber = success.LineNumber 
                                                        and overlap.ImportID = success.ImportID
                  where success.status = 'success')
```

Comment: run the subquery and see what shows up.

Comment: Thank you for formatting the table.I will practice a little bit more next time.

Comment: Subquery shows up  as                                                                                  
    195 5
    195 6

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I am looking for only Error1 records which don't have matching success.

Comment: I can't upvote yet, but the answers and queries are very helpful. I have marked one answered which worked for me first. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over complicating it, just select those with error where not exists same record with success

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.status = 'Error1'
AND NOT EXISTS 
(
   SELECT *
   FROM Table1 s
   WHERE s.Status = 'Success'
   AND s.ImportID = t1.ImportID
   AND s.LineNumber = t1.LineNumber
);
```

Comment: I can't believe that it could be so well structured,  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easier way to this, with `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT ImportID, LineNumber
FROM Table1
WHERE Status = 'Error1'

EXCEPT

SELECT ImportID, LineNumber
FROM Table1
WHERE Status = 'Success'
```

Note: `EXCEPT`, like `UNION`, will create a distinct result set.  If you don't need or want distinct results, then `EXISTS` will perform better.

Comment: This will give me Error2 records also. Actually in our system Error1 records are retried and we stop retrying after getting success or a different error.

Comment: @OscarAnad Not sure what you mean, it filters to only `Error1` records on the top half.  It will only display records that have an `Error1` and do not have a `Success`

Comment: It will not get Error2 records because there is `WHERE Status = 'Error1'` in the top query. It will work fine, however performance-wise this will not be nearly as good as `NOT EXISTS` solutions.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic I think it will the exact same in this case.  `EXISTS` answers will be correlated on the same two fields that will be compared in the `EXCEPT`.  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @AaronDietz `EXECPT` will add unnecessary sorting of two result-sets before joining them - same would be if there is `ORDER BY  ImportID, LineNumber` in the `EXISTS` solution. You can run them both and check the execution plans for yourself.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic Ah yeah, I almost added that the one difference would be the `DISTINCT` result set.  Same execution plan as an `EXISTS` query with `SELECT DISTINCT`.  Good point.

Comment: Thank you Aaron, This works as well. I don't know how I assumed that this will return other results.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.status = 'Error1' and 
      not exists (select 1
                  from table1 tt1
                  where tt1.importid = t1.importid and tt1.linenumber = t1.linenumber and
                        tt1.status = 'Success'
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple left join of [error1 table] left join [success table] and pick out the records which are not found in [success table]. Check the below query.

```
SELECT E.IMPORTID, E.LINENUMBER, E.STATUS
FROM
(SELECT IMPORTID, LINENUMBER FROM TABLE1 WHERE STATUS = 'Error1') E
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT IMPORTID, LINENUMBER FROM TABLE1 WHERE STATUS = 'Success') S
ON E.IMPORTID = S.IMPORTID AND E.LINENUMBER = S.LINENUMBER
WHERE S.IMPORTID IS NULL AND S.LINENUMBER IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ImportID, LineNumber
from Table1 t1
where Status in ('Success', 'Error1')
group by ImportID
having max(Status) = 'Error1'
```